# Как сделать замену буквенного кода кавычек?

Tags: javascript, html, api, angular

При нажатии на определенный город меняется адрес. Но работает не совсем корректно.

Есть код:

```
<div *ngIf="cityService.city.PROPERTY_ADDRESS_VALUE!== null">
    {{cityService.city.PROPERTY_ADDRESS_VALUE}}
</div>
```

Вот что выводит:

```
Абакан, 655017, Деловой центр &quot;Столица&quot;, ул. Щетинкина, 24
```

Вот что нужно убрать.. **`&quot;`**

Comment: `[innerHTML]=cityService.city.x`

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.

Comment: Но тут есть потенциальная проблема, если у вас в строке будут спец символы html - например `<` или `>` - тогда ваша разметка сломается.